# Local DB on Android sync to backend server? What are the options?

Tags: android, nosql, couchdb, cloudant

Local DB always sync to remote server sounds a great idea, because you get the responsiveness for using local DB, but also get sync crossing devices.

But can anybody talk about their experiences with couchbase on Android?

https://github.com/couchbase/Android-Couchbase/

What are other options out there? Cloudant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at [Touch-DB Android](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/TouchDB-Android). It's more compact than Android-Couchbase and is still regularly updated and maintained (I believe the main contributor is working on a big release, which is why the last update we two months ago). The framework is built on top of [Ektorp](http://ektorp.org/) and emulates a CouchDB database on your Android device.

Replication to and from a remote database is fairly intuitive and easy to set-up.

I use CloudAnt as my remote back end for my Android game.

Comment: Thank you! The Touch-DB is very promising. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you that in general, it works. e.g. I have an android app that syncs with iriscouch.com. But you might want to ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 0):

iBoxDB is another option. It is a lightweight database for java. You can customize replication.

https://github.com/iboxdb/forjava

Comment: interesting, anybody has real experience with this project?